# Throttling laravel app without authentication

Tags: php, laravel, ddos

We are running Laravel 4.2 site. This is just a news site and has no user authentication.

Since Saturday last week we started being flooded by dubious requests that have brought down the site.

To mitigate against fake requests we installed Apache mod_evasive (http://www.helicontech.com/ape/doc/mod_evasive.htm) without success. We have also tried fail2ban (http://www.fail2ban.org/) without success.

At the moment we're considering doing this from Laravel itself. Our search gave http://culttt.com/2015/12/28/dealing-with-brute-force-attacks-in-laravel/ but there seems to be questions about its effectiveness.

We are next considering upgrading to Laravel 5 and using throttling (https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#authentication-throttling) but realised this only works with authentication/logins, which we don't have.

Is there a way to use Laravel throttling without logins? What we need, basically, is to protect the controllers. Before a request is passed to the controllers we need to verify it's not a a DoS or DDoS.

Answer (score 1):

There are few tools to prevent this from happening. Not sure on Laravel way, but this is more on solving it on Apache or DNS level. Personally, I think this bad traffic should be blocked before it reaches our application or even better our server. Once it reached our server/application, it already eats resources even we giving bad response to those traffic

1. Use Fail2Ban to analyze your Apache logs and it will automatically identify bad IPs and block them. Refer [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-an-apache-server-with-fail2ban-on-ubuntu-14-04)
2. You can actually solve this quicly by subscribing paid service to block this at DNS level. One I can thing off is, [CloudFlare DDOS Protection](https://www.cloudflare.com/ddos/)

Comment: Eventually we'll implement a multiple level protection. In the meantime we just need a quick way to get back online. Then we can think of long term solution. As mentioned we already tried out Faio2Ban and other methods. Not that they don't work but probably we haven't learnt how to implement/integrate them properly.